# TFS 2018 Discussion only group?

Tags: tfs, tfs-security

Is there a way to create a security group that would lock down people similar to 'reader' access but allow them to add to the 'discussion' portion of WIs?

Answer (score 0):

No, we cannot achieve that, if set read access then the users cannot give the discussion comments.